# Was the contemporaneity of Nazi Germany and Imperial Japan coincidental or somehow structural?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, imperial-japan

Nazi Germany and Imperial Japan embarked on aggressive war plans on opposite sides of the globe at nearly the same time.

Was this a coincidence, or were there structural factors in the world system that made this happen?

The case for coincidence is obvious.  It's strengthened by the fact that there have always been aggressive states, so finding two on different sides of the world is not hard (you can do it today).  The fact that it was two industrialized powers is just coincidence.

Unfortunately, I only have a bachelor's in history so I can't even really speculate about the opposite case.  I've heard a few lectures about structural realism in international relations, so I know there are these kinds of discussion in faculty lounges.

Coincidence or more to the story?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  Why doesn't [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_powers) answer the question? "The Axis grew out of successive diplomatic efforts by Germany, Italy, and Japan to secure their own specific expansionist interests in the mid-1930s"

Comment: Three late-to-the-table would-be imperialists.

Comment: In general, I don't believe in coincidences.

Comment: At first thought... the nations enforcing the League of Nations and Treaty of Versailles and their Pacific territories (France, Britain, Netherlands) had war exhaustion and debt following WW1 which resulted in smaller, weaker militaries. They relied on arms reduction and other treaties to reduce military spending, and had less support to intervene when Germany and Japan violated them. Both Germany and Japan thought they came out worse from WW1 and following treaties.

Comment: Also note that Japan had been [fighting in China since 1931](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_invasion_of_Manchuria), two years before the Nazis took power. They had been [fighting for territory in Taiwan, China, Korea, Pacific Islands, and Russia since before 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_colonial_empire) so the "nearly at the same time" is not so at the same time.

Comment: States attack each other to gain space, unless there are colonies where to expand. Once colonies are no longer available, they return to attack each other again.

Comment: @Santiago Modern nations rarely need space. They attack each other to gain ***resources*** or to neutralize perceived threats.

Comment: Italy, Germany, and Japan attempting to grow, and bumped up against the British Empire. The British didn't like the competition, and two violent wars ensued.

Comment: @AstorFlorida - I had not realized that China was part of the British empire…

Comment: @JonCuster Qing China was not easy to dominate, but the British Empire was doing its best, with Hong Kong, Weihai, Hankou, Zhenjiang, Xiamen, Dalian, Tibet, and other places. They certainly had a presence in China since the Opium wars.

Comment: @AstorFlorida I'm not going to defend British imperialism, but "attempted to grow" sounds so benign, and "didn't like the competition" blames the British for two world wars. Germany, Italy, and Japan all "attempted to grow" by sacking neighboring sovereign nations. Britain got dragged into WW1 to guarantee the independence of Belgium, and into WW2 guaranteeing the independence of Poland. Japan was busy sacking Korea and China, needed oil for their war machine, so they attacked British, Dutch, and US territories to get it.

Comment: @AstorFlorida - and that is why Japan attacked China? To protect it from the British?

Comment: @Schwern Yes, [I don't care to much for colonialism](https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2022/12/2/how-british-colonial-policy-killed-100-million-indians). But, per the Japanese & Germans, "If the British can do it, why can't we?"

Comment: @JonCuster No, the Japanese Empire was only interested in expanding its sphere of influence. They were following the model of the other "modern" nations, with the British Empire and Germany their important role models.

Comment: @AstorFlorida Its extremely immoral to slaughter millions of innocent people. It's worse to claim it's ok because someone else also slaughtered innocent people. Nations don't get to take turns oppressing people. Japanese aggression is rooted in imperialism towards east Asia,  it's a complicated topic, but it does not excuse their racism and appalling behavior towards those same people once it was their "turn". Germany didn't even have that excuse.

Comment: @Schwern I agree, this is an awful story. Hundreds of millions were displaced or killed or worse. There is no excuse for the choice of "turns". OTOH, we shouldn't lie about history. Lebensraum was a real goal, along with its Japanese counterpart in East Asia.